# Several Android versions on same device (Kindle HD) possible?

Tags: android, bootloader, kindle-fire, kindle

I have an old Kindle Fire HD device (running FireOS), which I do not use anymore.

Now I would like to test it for my mobile app development in regards to Android. I read about being able to run Android, instead of FireOS (which for sure is unsupported by Amazon).

However I wonder, whether it is possible to install something like a boot loader in order to be able to switch to *different* Android OS versions?

Comment: Seems like a question suitable for XDA forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is posible on certain devices using specialized kernel with multiboot feature, for example Siyah kernel for SGS3. I don't know anything about kernel with this feature for Kindle HD.

Maybe it's possible to run multiboot by modifying /etc/fstab...